# COLLATE columns from linked server into another servers tables "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I usually use COLLATE after a column name when the two servers don't have the same collation. My linked server that I am pulling data from is "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and my target server, where I am inserting the linked server data, is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS".

I have tried in the code below to COLLATE and have not been successful. I am not able to alter table collation because dependent tables are pointing towards them. I would have to rebuild the tables and that's currently not an option.

Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 2055
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [DAT_Table] 

INSERT INTO [DAT_Table] 
  ([Entity]
  ,[Identifier]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Description]
  ,[PayType])

SELECT 
   HRORGANIZATION COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  ,STEPANDGRADESCHEDULE COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  ,DESCRIPTION COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), STEPANDGRADEVERSION, 111) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  ,CASE WHEN [PAYRATETYPE] = '1' THEN 'H' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS WHEN [PAYRATETYPE] = '2' THEN 'S' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS END AS PayType 


FROM [LinkedServer].[CS_Table]
```

Comment: I would always use Collate database_default which just uses whatever the local database is set to.

Comment: What is the datatype of PAYRATETYPE?

Comment: I tried the database_default to no avail. The PAYRATE TYPE is NAVCHAR(1) and being inserted into a column that is NAVCHAR(2000). This is usually an easy fix. I don't understand what could be wrong on this one. I've even tried just loading HRORGANIZATION to Entity and it still gets the error with COLLATE. Any advice would be amazing. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Could there be an admin setting or something that is not allowing me to collate data from a linked server?

Comment: Issue resolved. Script that uses this collated data was in a view and the view was blocking the collate.